# How to pass a string argument to `krun` in K framework?

Tags: kframework

In the K framework, one can use the `-c` switch of `krun` to pass to the initial configuration other variables then the default `$PGM`. For example, one may have this code:

```
configuration <T color="yellow">
                <k color="green"> $PGM:Pgm </k>
                <something> $SOMEARG:Int </something>
              </T>
```

and run `kompile imp.k; krun tests/sum.imp -cSOMEARG=3`, and the `$SOMEARG` variables gets the value `3`. However, I run into problems when I tried to pass a string:

```
configuration <T color="yellow">
                <k color="green"> $PGM:Pgm </k>
                <something> $SOMEARG:String </something>
              </T>
```

After `kompile`, the command

```
krun tests/sum.imp -cSOMEARG=\"hello\" --debug
```

outputs:

```
org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException: [Error] Critical: Parser returned a non-zero exit code: 113
Stdout:

Stderr:
[Error] Inner Parser: Parse error: unexpected token 'hello'.
    Source(<command line: -e>)
    Location(1,1,1,6)

    at org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException.create(KEMException.java:130)
    at org.kframework.utils.errorsystem.KEMException.criticalError(KEMException.java:39)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRun.externalParse(KRun.java:237)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRun.parseConfigVars(KRun.java:161)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRun.run(KRun.java:77)
    at org.kframework.krun.KRunFrontEnd.run(KRunFrontEnd.java:95)
    at org.kframework.main.FrontEnd.main(FrontEnd.java:62)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:118)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.runApplication(Main.java:108)
    at org.kframework.main.Main.main(Main.java:56)
```

How do I pass a string argument?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in the version of the option parsing library we are using that causes it to try to unquote quotation marks even though that is actually the role of the shell. It is fixed in the latest version of the options library. You can track the progress of the bug fix here: https://github.com/kframework/k/pull/1335

I expect it will be fixed in the very near future.